# Spring Boot - Angular - frontend-maven-plugin - Docker = cors error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker-compose, frontend-maven-plugin

I created a spring boot (3.0) backend application and used an angular frontend for it.
I want to use the frontend-maven-plugin to put the frontend in the static folder of the spring boot application. This works as long as I run the application in a local environment, but when I create a docker image of it, the frontend and backend can no longer communicate with each other due to a cors error.

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ...

  app:
    image: <dockerImage>
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

In the angular application, the environment.ts contains this:
`baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/api/'`

How to configure the frontend to be able to communicate with the backend in the docker container?
I am not a frontend developer, and this is for learning purposes only :)
Thank you for your answers!